# Rotate currencies with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a simple script that rotate currencies with a 1 second interval on all spans with a class = value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var str1 = "£";
        var str2 = "€";
        var str3 = "$";

        $("span.value").text(str1); //how can I rotate between the str1, 2 and 3 with a 1 second interval?
    });
</script>
```

HTML looks something like this:

```
<h2>Get <span class="value"></span> discount.</h2>
<h3>Get <span class="value"></span> extra.</h3>
```

and so on....

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The following will hopefully suffice:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currencyIndex = 0;
    var currencies = ['&pound;', '&euro;', '$'];

    var cInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $("span.value").text(function() {
            return currencies[currencyIndex];
        });

        currencyIndex = (currencyIndex + 1) % currencies.length;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Remember to use entities in HTML, not the symbols or you will get odd results.

Comment: +1 on using entities.  The user's font may not have the currency symbols in the same spot, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) function:

```
var currencies = ['£', '€', '$'];
var index = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
    var value = currencies[(index++) % currencies.length];
    $('span.value').text(value);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise making them an array:

```
var i;
window.setInterval(function() {
  $('span.value').text(currencies[(++i % currencies.length) + 1]);
},1000)
```